# Python3 Unable to store stdout to variable

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

My case is a little bit specific. I'm trying to run a Python program using Python for testing purposes. The case is as follows:

```py
# file1.py
print("Hello world")
```

```py
# file1.test.py
import io
import sys
import os
import unittest

EXPECTED_OUTPUT = "Hello world"

class TestHello(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_hello(self):
        sio = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = sio
        os.system("python3 path/to/file1.py")
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        print("captured value:", sio.getvalue())
        self.assertEqual(sio.getvalue(), EXPECTED_STDOUT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

But nothing ends up in the `sio` variable. This way and similar ways are introduced online but they don't seem to work for me. My Python version is `3.8.10` but it doesn't really matter if this works better in some other version, I can switch to that.

Note: I know that if I was using an importable object this might be easier, but right now I need to know how to catch the output of another file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stdout redirection does not work like this - this will change the stdout variable inside your Python process. But by using `os.system`, you are running another process, that will re-use the same terminal pseudo-files your parent process is using.

If you want to log a subprocess, the way to do it is to use the `subprocess` modules calls, which allow you to redirect the subprocess output. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Also, the subprocess won't be able to use a StringIO object from the parent process (it is not an O.S. level object, just an in-process Python object with a `write` method). The docs above include instructions about using the special object `subprocess.PIPE` which allows for in-memory communication, or, you can just pass an ordinary filesystem file, which you can read afterwards.